# Servlet context attribute from Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, applicationcontext

I'm trying to get rid of really old servlets and add in their place casual services.

Is this possible to get the same data from the application context as I was previously taking from the servlet context?

More specifically, I'm trying to get attribute `servletContext.getAttribute("org.directwebremoting.ContainerList")` from application context, but `ApplicationContext` doesn't have `getAttribute` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses `Servlet`s as backing technology. So you just need to obtain the `ServletContext` related to that `Servlet` and retrieve the attributes.

For the root context, use [`WebApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/WebApplicationContext.html). This interface adds a `getServletContext()` method to the generic ApplicationContext interface.

```java
Object attribute = webApplicationContext
                .getServletContext()
                .getAttribute("org.directwebremoting.ContainerList");
```